# Identifying & Measuring a Signal in Noise

Tags: matlab, snr

I am searching for the signal circled in green in the 2.4GHz range. The sampling rate in this image is 800kHz, my setup is [this power meter](https://www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/ZX47-60+.pdf) hooked up to an oscilloscope. 
[image]

The three troughs are always the same time away from each other, but their amplitude (which I want to measure) changes. How can I detect this signal and measure its amplitude when the amplitude is lower than the amplitude of the other things going on in this frequency band that I don't care about (in red)?

I am a beginner to signal processing using Matlab. Any suggestions would be appreciated no matter how obvious they may seem to you :)

Comment: I would use a filter matched to the specific waveform you're looking for. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matched_filter

Comment: if you need to get rid of the noise while keeping the main signal, try total variance denoising.